# Is it there a way to get the crash log that occurs on users' device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, logging

Some users reported there are bugs when run my app on their device.
Is it there a way to get the crash log that occurs on users' device?

Or is there any solution to catch all crash log for cocoa touch?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common chrash logs are available through itunesconnect.

Also, the crash logs get synchronized to the Mac or PC. Maybe not the latest news, but this link should get you going: http://aplus.rs/apple/how-to-find-crash-logs-for-iphone-applications-on-mac-vista-and-xp/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reduce the amount of effort users need to go to, something like [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) is quite good (I remember seeing a handy wrapper around it recently but I lost the URL).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out apphance (http://apphance.com). It provides remote access to a test user device including logs written by developer, crash logs and more....

Disclaimer : I am CTO of company which created apphance and co-creator of it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net) and really like it. It's free, and easy to install on your server.
If you want a hosted solution, I have heard a lot of praises for [Crashlytics.com](http://crashlytics.com/), but did not personally tested it (commercial product).

And forget iTunes Connect if you care about fixing all crashes. Often, you won't see crash happening in there (might be because users do not sync and many other reasons).